# Download popup will show up when navigating

Tags: support, google-chrome, navigation

I am not sure if it is a problem with Google Chrome, or maybe one of the extensions on my browser.

In last month, in many cases when crawling in Stackoverflow or meta site, browser open a download dialog (or display json content) instead of the requested HTML page.

I tried searching the meta, but couldn't find a duplicate bug.

Chrome version:  56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
OS: MacOs Sierra

**UPDATE1**: I disabled all my extensions, and the issue is still reproducible.

**UPDATE2**: It is reproducible in incognito mode. I tried to reproduce it on HTTPS, and I couldn't. But since it is a random bug, I am not sure if the issue is with http

**UPDATE3**: no error in console. But in case that I got the download popup, I tried to see the ajax call response, and it was empty. (I try to capture an image)

**UPDATE4** I tried with other browsers (FF, Safari), and there was no problem. I also tried with a few other Mac machines, and I could reproduce the bug, but not on Windows machines.

[image]

Comment: Does it happen when you disable your extensions?

Comment: What links cause this json content to come up? Are you browsing over HTTPS or not?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the browser developer tools?

Comment: So, this is intermittent? One time you click on a link, everything works as expected, another time, same link you get json?

Comment: Yes that is the case, and many others.

Comment: Examples: (1) refreshing a page, (2) clicking on a tab/link several times, (3) opening a stackoverflow page from google result

Comment: Even while I was commenting, I got a json object replaced with my comment (or when I was trying to upload the image). The strange thing is it happens in http not https, but even when I force the page to use https, after a few click here and there it may redirect to http

Comment: If you truly can't reproduce when browsing over HTTPS, then chances are that your ISP (or someone else between you and us) is injecting content into the pages, causing the issue.

Comment: The fact that it only happens over HTTP strongly implies that you're a victim of a man-in-the-middle attack. Use HTTPS Everywhere or similar to force SE sites to load over TLS.

Comment: I will investigate that. I have two quick questions. (1) Is it normal that Google gives me the link to a http page not https? (2) Should I remove this question or answer it when I fix my issue?

Comment: To be more accurate about the google results. If I copy the url address, it is https, but when I click it goes to http, and I will get this in the dev console: Navigated to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine

Comment: One more case: clicking on the notifications has http by default, not https

Comment: Since SE still does not fully support HTTPS, it's expected the Google results will point to HTTP. As for copy URL, it's Google's address, which is indeed secure, e.g. `https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj1g9vxs7LSAhWELcAKHc08DLsQFggZMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F11627279%2Frunning-java-helloworld&usg=AFQjCNELN1-DeRzha9oOg7t1DgW-gtpO0g&bvm=bv.148073327,d.bGg` which when processed by Google, performs a redirect to the actual, non HTTPS, url address. (don't try to copy&paste URL in the comment, it broken due to bug)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the conversation in the comments, we found that the issue is happening when a page is loading in HTTP mode, not HTTPS.

Some folks believed that it should be an issue in my network and probably there is a man-in-the-middle. It makes sense to some extent because I saw similar issues on websites other than SO-family. But, it is strange that the issue does not happen on other browsers (e.g. FF, Safari)

Although I couldn't find the root cause of the problem, I fixed it with a workaround. Using a chrome extension, I forced certain domains to be redirected to HTTPS.

This solution works, but since it does not the best answer, I keep this question unanswered for further possible answers.